# Change background colour (scrolling) when an element comes to a certain point (Responsive)

Tags: html, tags, responsive, background-color

Sorry guys, I am very new to Javascript. I have searched for similar solutions before posting here.

I want to change the background colour, every time that multiple div tags, with specific ids, come 150 pixels before they reach the browser top. I want it to work in different devices correctly. I tried different things in javascript but none gave me the responsiveness I want. When I reduce the browser's width, the text is folding and the div/ids positions change. So, my logic is... if, for example, a div with id="One" is 150px from top, change the background colour.

```js
var one = document.getElementById("one");
var two = document.getElementById("two");
var three = document.getElementById("three");

window.addEventListener('scroll', () => {
  if(one.getBoundingClientRect().top < 150){
    document.body.addClass = "bg-one"; 
  }
});
```

```css
.site-main{
  background-color: white;
}
.bg-one{
  background-color: red;
}
.bg-two{
  background-color: blue;
}
.bg-three{
  background-color: yellow;
}
```

```html
<body class="site-main" id="main">
  <div id="one" class="">Text</div>
  <div id="two" class="">Text</div>
  <div id="three" class="">Text</div
</body>
```

I was thinking about that, but it doesn't work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My solution would be to add an event listener on window scroll

```
  window.onscroll = function(){ft_onscroll()};
```

in this function, you get the current scroll position. Compare it to your element position to do what you want.

```
one_y = one.getBoundingClientRect().top;
function ft_onscroll(){
    y = window.scrollY;
    if(one_y > y){
       //change background color 
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I change it a bit and now it works like a charm. You are the best!!

Answer (score 0):

I made it. My final code is this. Maybe I will make it shorter.

```js
window.onscroll = function(){
  fromTop_onscroll();
};

function fromTop_onscroll(){
  var main = document.getElementById("main");
  var one = document.getElementById("one");
  one_distance = one.getBoundingClientRect().top; // distance from top
  var two = document.getElementById("two");
  two_distance = two.getBoundingClientRect().top; // distance from top

  if(one_distance < 150 && two_distance > 150){
    main.classList.add("bg-one");
    main.classList.remove("site-main");
    main.classList.remove("bg-two");
  } else if (two_distance < 150 && one_distance < 0) {
    main.classList.add("bg-two");
    main.classList.remove("bg-one");
  } else if (one_distance > 150 && two_distance > 150){
    main.classList.add("site-main");
    main.classList.remove("bg-two");
    main.classList.remove("bg-one");
  }
}
```